# Preg Replace Wordpress tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm displaying wordpress content on my own site.

However the content has such things as:

`[caption id="attachment_367" align="aligncenter" width="432" caption="Version 2010!!"]`

I would basically like to strip anything thats inside [] and the [] themselves.

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are they all `[caption]`'s or are there other `[shortcode]` type content tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you want is `/\[.*?\]/`

```
<?php
$old_content = 'Hello [caption id="attachment_367" align="aligncenter" width="432" caption="Version 2010!!"] World!';
$new_content = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '', $old_content);
echo $new_content; // result: "Hello World!"
?>
```

Comment: Please add a '?' after the '*' (make it ungreedy), or make it `\\[[^\\]]*\\]` (anything but ']'), otherwise, this string will fail to show 'this valid content should stay'  : `[ to remove ] this valid content should stay [another remove]`.

Answer (score 1):

So code like `[caption id="attachment_367" align="aligncenter" width="432" caption="Version 2010!!"]` looks like a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to me.

If you want it to do nothing, you could add this to the `functions.php` file in your theme (if your theme does not have that file, you would need to create it and enclose this code inside `<?php` and `?>`:

```
function do_nothing_caption() {
  return '';
}
add_shortcode('caption', 'do_nothing_caption');
```